# How to use react-alert with React component that is defined as ES6 class

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert in my project, but the examples are porvided for the React components that are declared as functions but my React components are declared as classes like:

```
class ConnectedOrderForm extends Component {

    //const statusAlert = useAlert();

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

   render() {
        return (
            <div>Test</div>
        )
   }
}

const OrderForm = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedOrderForm));
export default OrderForm;
```

When I am trying to call `useAlert().show('OK');` from class event, I am getting:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

So, how can I use this react-alert hook from ES6 class component?

The solution was to use either export code:

```
const OrderForm = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedOrderForm));
export default withAlert()(OrderForm);

const OrderForm = withAlert()(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedOrderForm)));
export default OrderForm;
```

And call:

```
this.props.alert.show()
```

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/blog/using-hooks-in-classes/ or just call it directly as per the [react-alert docs](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert#user-content-usage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the docs it would seem that you should not be using the `useAlert` hook but rather the `withAlert` HOC. Hooks can only be used in functional components, and since you want to use a class, you would need to the `withAlert` HOC.

Here is an example of that that would look like

```
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const alert = this.props.alert;
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
         alert.show('Oh look, an alert!')
        }}
       >
        Show Alert
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default withAlert()(App)
```

Comment: Thow error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {code, message}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead......`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one?

```
import {alert} from 'react-alert';

alert.show('Some message', {
  ... options
})
```

UPD. Sorry, this is wrong answer, Please take a look here:
https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert/issues/116

Comment: Of course it does not work, because react-alert does not export alert.

Comment: sorry, there are closed issue for that:
https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert/issues/116

Comment: Thx, the link helped, but I am bound to Accept the other answert for being more explicit. Thx.