# How can I display messages in component with react-alert?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, alert, toast

I'm using reactjs.
I want to show alert in component with react-alert component.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert
I wrap the index.js file as given at.

but when I try to use `alert.show ("sdfsdfsdfsf")` in the form, I get the following error.

do I show a message in a form?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App/App';

import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const options = {
    // you can also just use 'bottom center'
    position: positions.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    timeout: 5000,
    offset: '30px',
    // you can also just use 'scale'
    transition: transitions.SCALE
};
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
            <App/>
        </AlertProvider>
    </Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

myForm.js

```
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
const alert = useAlert();
class myForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
.........

render() {
return(
<div> alert.show("Alert test") </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a function / method inside the render method unless it is wrapped in curly braces. Curly braces are required in jsx to let the parser know that you want to run some javascript code.

Try the following:

```
render() {
   return (
     <div>{alert.show("Alert test")}</div>
   );
}
```

The react-alert package on npm also has a nice example when using an onClick handler
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert

```
const App = () => {
  const alert = useAlert()

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        alert.show('Oh look, an alert!')
      }}
    >
      Show Alert
    </button>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: class CustomerDebt extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
     super (props);
how do I call it in it?
error as in the picture.

Comment: You will need to move your const alert into the render method before the return statement.

```
class myForm extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {
      const alert = useAlert();
      return (
           <div> alert.show("Alert test") </div>) 
      );
   }

Comment: You are trying to use a hook inside of a class component. You cannot do that according to the react docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both). You will need to either change your component to follow the functional component pattern or use a version of the library that works with classes

Comment: you can use hooks in class components using HOC. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975445/how-to-use-react-alert-with-react-component-that-is-defined-as-es6-class

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
render(){                                                            
  return(
  <div> alert.show("Alert test") </div>                                    
   )
}
```

But you need to use an event to display that alert.

Use this instead:

```
render(){ 
  return(                                                                
    <div                                                             
      onClick={() => 
        {alert.show('Alert test')}
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
 50 | const alert = useAlert();
  51 | 
  52 | class CustomerDebt extends Component {
  53 |   constructor(props)