# add react-alert in class compoent of reacts js and showing alert if axios post is sucess

Tags: reactjs, axios

i am trying to add react-alert in class compoent of reacts js and show alert if axios post is sucess

but i am getting the following error how can i fix this

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): alert.show is not a function`

`import { withAlert } from "react-alert";`

```
 componentWillMount() {
  
   handleCheckClick = (e, stateVal, index, alert) => {

    axios
      .patch("customer/", Data, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert.show("Oh look, an sucess!");
     
      })
      .catch((error) => {
              alert.show("Oh look, an error!");
      });

  
  };

  render() {
    const alert = this.props.alert;
    return (
   <div>hello</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you wrap your Root component with `Alert Provider`.

For basic template : `npm install --save react-alert react-alert-template-basic`

```
import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';

const Root = () => (
  <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
    <App />
  </AlertProvider>
)
```

And in your component..

```
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert';

class Medicine extends React.Component {
  handleCheckClick = (alert) => {
    axios
      .patch("customer/", Data, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert.show("Oh look, an sucess!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert.show("Oh look, an error!");
      });
  };

  render() {
    const alert = this.props.alert;

    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.handleCheckClick(alert)}>
        hello
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAlert()(Medicine)
```

Comment: i have export at top  like this

Comment: export default class Medicine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

Comment: so how can i  add export default withAlert()(App) in my code

Comment: pls help me i dont know what to do

Comment: Are you using this alert in `Medicine` component ?

Comment: yes i also want to use this in many other compoent also

Comment: @meon Then use `export default withAlert()(Medicine)` in your `Medicine` component. Just make sure you wrap you root component with `AlertProvider`. I have updated my answer with `Medicine` component..

Comment: You can use it in any component that is wrapped inside `AlertProvider`.

Comment: its really time consuming becoause i have more than 100 classcompontes and changing every  `export default class classname extends React.Components`  is not easy  i pls give an alternative

Comment: Just remove the `export default` from `export default class classname extends React.Components` and add this `export default withAlert()(className)` at the end of the file. Like @PR7 mentioned, you need to wrap the component where you wanna use the alert.

Comment: oke still i am getting `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): alert.show is not a function` this error

Comment: Maybe because we did not pass the alert to `handleCheckClick()`. I have updated the answer now. Please check.

Comment: @PR7 i passed  alert now my  handleCheckClick  looks like this `handleCheckClick = (e, stateVal, index, alert) => {`   and now getting this error   `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')`

Comment: @meon can you please create a small demo to replicate this issue on Codesandbox ? Only with one component...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-brook-2murn9?file=/src/medicine.js @PR7 i have created a example pls check

Comment: Fixed, here you go : https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-haze-neq5s5?file=/src/medicine.js

Comment: @PR7 it does work but it too lag it takes about 5 seconds to show up

Comment: its not practical to use it this way pls help me resuce the lag

Comment: @meon The delay is due to the network request. Check in the network tab in developer tools how much time the network request is taking.

Comment: For me it takes between 1 and 1.5 second. So the alert shows after around 1.5 seconds for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling alert, but you haven't defined alert anywhere, hence why you get alert.show is not a function.

Try this:

```
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
...
const alert = useAlert();
alert.show('Look, an alert!')
```

More info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert

Comment: its not possible to use useAlert() in a classcomponet

Comment: i was following this answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975445/how-to-use-react-alert-with-react-component-that-is-defined-as-es6-class

Comment: @meon No, you cannot use `useAlert` in class component.

Comment: so what is an alternative fot useAlert

Comment: check my anwer, make sure you wrap your Root component with Provider.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you wrapped your exported component with the HOC `withAlert` provided by the library like so

```
export default withAlert()(//your component)
```

you should be able to access alert from this.props

```
  handleCheckClick = () => {

    axios
      .patch("customer/", Data, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.alert.show("Oh look, an sucess!");
     
      })
      .catch((error) => {
              this.props.alert.show("Oh look, an error!");
      });

  
  };
```